# How to improve the php memory limit in Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, php, server-setup, magento-cloud

I've installed a Magento Cloud 2.3.5 and I don't have access to the server configuration.

How can I configure a new **PHP Memory Limit**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the file `php.ini` at the root of the project. If you need to increase the PHP memory limit:

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```

For a list of recommended PHP configuration settings, see [Required PHP settings](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html).

After pushing your file, you can check that the custom PHP configuration has been added to your environment by [creating an SSH tunnel](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/env/environments-start.html#env-start-tunn) to your environment and entering:

```
cat /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

You can also increase the MySQL, Redis, and ElasticSearch resources in the file `.magento/services.yaml`.

```
# The services of the project.
#
# Each service listed will be deployed to power your project.

mysql:
    type: mysql:10.2
    disk: 8192

redis:
    type: redis:5.0

elasticsearch:
    type: elasticsearch:6.8
    disk: 1024
```

Reference: [Magento DevDocs - Customize php.ini settings](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-conf-files_magento-app.html#customize-phpini-settings)